# Ajax spinner displaying even when function to display it is not called (after there is an ajax call)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using a spinner on my AJAX calls. I implemented the binding code inside a function so I can use it whenever I want and avoid certain AJAX calls from using the spinner. For instance, I have a username and email existence checking onkeyup and obviously I do not want the spinner to show whenever a key is pressed.

The way I implemented it is works however if client-side validation completes, an ajax call is fired on the registration page for instance, and an error is sent back, the username and email will start showing the spinner whenever a key is pressed.

Here is the code:

HTML

```
<div id="spinner" class="spinner hidden">
    <img id="img-spinner" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/images/spinner.gif" alt="Loading"/>
</div>
```

Mask function

```
    function show_hide_loading_mask() {
        $("#spinner").bind("ajaxSend", function() {
            $(this).show();
            $.blockUI({ message: '' }); //Set message to empty to remove default Loading message and show spinner instead
        }).bind("ajaxStop", function() {
            $(this).hide();
            $.unblockUI();
        }).bind("ajaxError", function() {
            $(this).hide();
            $.unblockUI();
        });
    }
```

The form submission call

```
$('#frmMyForm').submit(function(){
      if (validate()) {
        show_hide_loading_mask();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/path",
            data: $('#frmMyForm').serialize(),
            dataType: "json",

            success: function(data){
               if (data.response == "OK") {
                    console.log('OK');
               } else {
                console.log('NOT OK');
               }
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('Exception...');
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log('client side validation failed');
    }
    return false; // do not actually submit
  })
```

Validate function:

```
function validate() {
    var param1 = $('#txtParam1').val();
    var param2 = $('#txtParam2').val();
    return param1.length >= 5 && param2.length >= 5 //return true when both are at least 5 chars long
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening after a trip to the server? When there is an ajaxStop this should become again disabled.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you should bind the `ajaxStop` event on the spinner's div.

What you're trying to do can be acomplished by using [.ajaxError()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) and/or [.ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this. The problem was that once the function was being called, it kept on being binded with the ajax functions.

By namespacing the ajax functions this problem can be solved. I now have two functions:

```
function show_loading_mask() {
    $(document).bind("ajaxStart.showSpinner", function() {
        $('#spinner').show();
        $.blockUI({ message: '' }); //Set message to empty to remove default Loading message and show spinner instead
    });

    $(document).bind("ajaxStop.showSpinner", function() {
        $('#spinner').hide();
        $.unblockUI();
    });

    $(document).bind("ajaxError.showSpinner", function() {
        $('#spinner').hide();
        $.unblockUI();
    });
}

function no_loading_mask() {
    $(document).unbind('.showSpinner');
}
```

Then before every ajax call, I call the above methods accordingly. This way, I show the spinner only for those ajax calls which are needed.